# Как сделать чтобы изначально была отправка форма а затем уже работа js?

Tags: javascript, php

На секунду появляется изменение цвета и пропадает. Я так предполагаю потому, что происходит отправка формы.
PHP код

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
<form method="post" action="">
<input id="chislo" type="text" name="chislo">
<input id="submit" type="submit" value="Определить">

</form>
<div class="" id="block"></div>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['chislo']) );
{

$min = $_POST['chislo'];

$min = $min % 60;

$min = $min % 5;
 
if ($min !=0 and $min <= 3 ) echo 'Сейчас горит зеленый'; 
if ($min == 0 or $min > 3 ) echo 'Сейчас горит красный'; 
}
?>
  


 <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

JS Код

```
let input = document.getElementById("chislo");
let otpravka = document.getElementById("submit");
let block = document.querySelector("div");

otpravka.addEventListener("click", () => {
    let is = input.value;
    is = is % 60;

    is = is % 5;
     
    if (is !=0 && is <= 3 ) {
        block.className = "green";
    }
    if (is == 0 || is > 3 ){ 
block.className = "red";
    } 
})
```

Comment: Вы либо логику перекраски дива уносите в PHP, либо из PHP вытаскиваете в JS. После отправки формы, страница перегружается. После загрузки, страница не помнит, что делала ранее(если заранее не сохранить данные локально), да и у вас скрипт работает по клику...